# Каскадное сохранение в JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Есть класс `User`, он содержит `Set<UserRole>` с несколькими значениями, делаю insert, выдает класса `User`, он должен делать insert в две таблицы, но делает запись только на одну таблицу `Users`, а в таблицу `UserRoles` не добавляет записи.

```
public class User  {

private String username;
private String password;
private boolean enabled;
private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

public User() {}

public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public User(String username, String password,
            boolean enabled, Set<UserRole> userRole) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.userRole = userRole;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 60)
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return this.enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
    return this.userRole;
}

public void setUserRole(Set<UserRole> userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
}
```

и класс UserRole

```
public class UserRole{

private Integer userRoleId;
private User user;
private String role;

public UserRole() {
}

public UserRole(User user, String role) {
    this.user = user;
    this.role = role;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_role_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getUserRoleId() {
    return this.userRoleId;
}

public void setUserRoleId(Integer userRoleId) {
    this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getRole() {
    return this.role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
```

}

и один DAO

```
public void addUser(User user) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
}
```

Почему он записывает только на одну таблицу, хотя в Set добавляю два значения.

Comment: Если вопрос еще актуален, вы забыли поставить каскадные операции.  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#cascade() по умолчанию они не выполняются. Думаю вам подойдёт `CascadeType.ALL`, а так же `orphanRemoval=true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, что вы забыли указать `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}`. Поэтому при сохранении происходит сохранение той Entity, для который вы вызываете `save`, но каскадного сохранения не происходит. Надо добавить:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
    return this.userRole;
}
```